# How to manage process.env.NODE_ENV on Vercel

Tags: node.js, next.js, environment-variables, vercel

I have a Next Js app on Vercel and I've set various environment variables related to the database, etc, both for development and for production. All these variables work.

But I can't figure out how I can use the **process.env.NODE_ENV** that I use in local env in the dev build. For example, if I want to change the text logo in dev it doesn't work (in local yes, but on Vercel no)

```
<span>{process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? `${siteConfig.name} DEV` : siteConfig.name}</span>
```

I set the dev branch for preview.
[image]

I also tried to set these variables in this way, but of course, it doesn't work
[image]

Is that the correct way to approach this thing? How can I change, for example, the ui based on the environment?
Thanks

Comment: wild guess: it is "reserved" keyword and overwritten somehow. Maybe try another name for the variable?

Comment: @grekier thanks, but how do I match them?

Comment: I see you are using it in html/jsx/tsx. If it is from the client, you need to prefix the env with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to be accessible there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `next build` sets `NODE_ENV=production` automatically.

Since both Production and Preview deployments on Vercel run `next build`, they both set `NODE_ENV=production` automatically because `next build` performs production optimizations, one of those is ensuring React uses the production version.

I suggest using a different env var name for your use case such as `SITE_NAME=Dev`. Then you can write your code like the following:

```
<span>{process.env.SITE_NAME || siteConfig.name}</span>
```

Answer (score 8):

[Vercel docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables/system-environment-variables) state:

> If the environment variable `NODE_ENV` is unassigned, Next.js
> automatically assigns `development` when running the `next dev`
> command, or `production` for all other commands.

In your case, consider avoiding the use of `NODE_ENV` entirely and instead use [Vercel System Variables](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables/system-environment-variables); particularly `VERCEL_ENV` which tells you the Vercel Environment that the app is deployed and running on.

[image: Vercel System Variables]